# Simple databinding not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to make a simple app, a stopwatch. It works fine if I'm not doing the data binding. Here's my XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="StopWatch.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:StopWatch"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="318" Width="233">
<Window.Resources>
    <s:StopWatchViewModel x:Key="swViewModel" x:Name="swViewModel"></s:StopWatchViewModel>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource swViewModel}"> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="128*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="49" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,50,0,0" Name="txtTime" Text="{Binding Path=Message}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Content="Start" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,15,0,0" Name="startBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" Click="startBtn_Click" />
    <Button Content="Stop" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,15,0,0" Name="stopBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" Click="stopBtn_Click" />
    <Button Content="Reset" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="140,15,0,0" Name="resetBtn" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59"/>
</Grid>
```

and here is the code in MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private StopWatchViewModel stopwatch;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stopwatch = new StopWatchViewModel();
    }

    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    private void stopBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

and here's the code in StopWatchViewModel.cs

```
class StopWatchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DispatcherTimer timer;
    private Stopwatch stopwatch;
    private string message;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
            if (message != value)
            {
                message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
    }

    public StopWatchViewModel()
    {
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
        stopwatch.Reset();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(); // Doesn't work.
        // Message = "hello"; does not work too!
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know where I got it wrong.

**EDIT**: I got it working. So here's the working code for anyone's reference.

XAML, change the original to this

```
<Window x:Class="StopWatch.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:StopWatch"
Title="MainWindow" Height="318" Width="233">
<Grid> // partial code
```

and in behind code, change the constructor based on Erno's suggestion.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new StopWatchViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your Message property like this and it will work:

```
 public string Message
 {
     get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
     set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
 }

 public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof(string), 
     typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
```

**EDIT** after posting my solution I noticed you changed all the code into a ViewModel solution... feel free to ignore or go back to your first set of code.

In your new code you are creating TWO instances of the ViewModel, one in code and one in the resources. That is not good as you are manipulating the one in code and binding to the one in the resources(xaml)

**EDIT:**
change your constructor to this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    stopwatch = new StopWatchViewModel();
    this.DataContext = stopwatch;
}
```

That's all

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try this too. I get it to bind but now, it just update the property once.

Comment: This is exactly the problem: your buttons start/stop the private stopwatch, but your binding is linked to the Resource-ViewModel.
You should remove the resource and instead provide a public Property "ViewModel" that exposes your ViewModel, then of course you also need to bind to this property. You could give your Window an attribute x:Name="wnd" and then change the DataContext-Binding of the Grid to something like
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, ElementName=wnd}">

Comment: Yup, that is the problem. Good call Emo.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. But I'm not quite sure how to achieve what you said. Right now, I've remove the instance of ViewModel in the XAML, but I'm not sure how to expose the ViewModel. I made the field ViewModel public, it doesn't work even if it does work, it's not going to be a good design.

Comment: Just create an instance of the ViewModel (as you did) and assign it to the DataContext of the Window. There is no need for a property. Let me know if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't figure it out. What I did is, delete the resource in XAML and in code behind it, I have wnd.DataContext = this; but now it doesn't show anything. Before this at least I have 00:00:00. Can you show the code if possible. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem here is that you don't have any mechanism for letting WPF know that your property is updated. Basically you have two options here:

1. Make Message into a Dependancy Property.
2. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that it let's the GUI know when the message have been updated.

To make sure that you have all parts for getting `INotifyPropertyChanged` to work, check that you did all of this:

1. Define the event `PropertyChanged`.
2. Make a private `NotifyPropertyChanged` method to raise the event. This method should take a string parameter (name of the property) and raise the event like this : `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(<nameofproperty>)`. The reason to make this method is to put the null check and invocation details in one place.
3. In the property setter, call `NotifyPropertyChanged` with the correct name (case-sensitive) of the property **after** the value has changed.

Comment: I've edited my code. It still doesn't work. Can you check it again?

Comment: If it's still not working, I think I have to see the updated code where you have reimplemented INotifyPropertyChanged, sinc it has to be a error in that implementation. Please add that code as an edit to your post above, and we'll figure it out :)

Comment: One more thing. Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside the tick method where Message is actually altered, to see that the program actually calls Tick? (It should, but if the statement is never called, it would explain your problem)

Comment: I've got it work, but it only wont update for every tick. It stays at 00:00:00. Well at least, there is improvement..

Comment: Have you tried setting the interval for the DispatcherTimer? I'm not to familiar with it, but since you have not given any interval, maybe it's only running once (setting the time to 00:00:00) and then never run again. Try setting the Interval to new TimeSpan(0,0,1). Then it should at least update every second. Probably not often enough for a stop watch, but you will at least see if it works or not.

Comment: See Emo's answer here. The problem is (after the restructure of your code above) that the start and stop buttons are linked to the instance of the ViewModel you have created in code, but the TextBlock is bound to the instance you have created from XAML, and that's the reason it always shows 00:00:00 since you have no way of starting it.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the property won't get noticed if you don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged correctly. So you should do that first. Maybe you missed something when you did it earlier.

Comment: Hi, I've implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged. I have edited my post as well.